# How can I load a resource bundle into Native image?

Tags: java, jpa, aws-lambda, eclipselink, graalvm-native-image

AWS Lambda Graalvm native image can't load resource bundle for org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle, located in the fat jar.

I'm deploying a Java AWS lambda function using a Graalvm native image on a custom runtime.
This lambda function use eclipse persistence jpa into a Graalvm native image CE 22.2.0 for java11-linux-amd64, to connect to RDS postgre database.

Eclipse persistence jpa is trying to load the resource bundle to describe the specific error on a query execution. Trying to load the resource bundle I get the following exception:

```
Resource bundle lookup must be loaded during native image generation: class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError
com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Resource bundle lookup must be loaded during native image generation: class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle
at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89)
at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.localization.LocalizationSupport.getBundleContentOf(LocalizationSupport.java:93)
at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.localization.BundleContentSubstitutedLocalizationSupport.getBundleContentOf(BundleContentSubstitutedLocalizationSupport.java:120)
at java.util.ListResourceBundle.loadLookup(ListResourceBundle.java:47)
at java.util.ListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ListResourceBundle.java:130)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:555)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:521)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:133)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:271)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:164)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:141)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:117)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:104)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:88)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1726)
```

Taking a look to JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle, the bundle seems to be loaded from the same package:

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME = JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle.class.getPackage().getName() + ".jpa_jpql_validation";
```

For native image generation, I'm using maven shade plugin and the fat jar contains the properties file mentioned before in the location that is expected to be. Indeed, during build time, I'm including the resouce-config.json file to discover the bundle properties as follows (obtained from java -agentlib:native-image-agent):

```
{
  "resources":{
  "includes":[]},
  "bundles":[{
    "name":"org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jpa_jpql_validation",
    "locales":[""]
  }]
}
```

and the reflect-config:

```
[
{
  "name": "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryProblemResourceBundle",
  "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
  "allPublicConstructors": true,
  "allDeclaredMethods": true,
  "allPublicMethods": true,
  "allDeclaredClasses": true,
  "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
  "name": "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser",
  "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
  "allPublicConstructors": true,
  "allDeclaredMethods": true,
  "allPublicMethods": true,
  "allDeclaredClasses": true,
  "allPublicClasses": true
}
]
```

As last effort, I also included the build arg into maven task triying to incluide the resource, with no luck:

```
-H:IncludeResources=.*/jpa_jpql_validation.properties$
```

Any help or guidance be appreciate.
Thanks in advance.